# An example of a manifold which cannot be embedded in a $\Bbb R^5$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

I was reading a bit about characteristic classes when I came across the following theorem:

*If a manifold of dimension $4n$ can be embedded as a hypersurface in $\Bbb R^{4n+1}$, then all it's pontryagin numbers vanish*

I was looking for an example of a manifold of dimension $4n$, which cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^{4n+1}$. That is, I'm looking for a $4n$-manifold which has non-zero pontryagin numbers. Since I'm new to this concept, I've no idea how to proceed. Is there a natural example of such a manifold?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^4$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^5$, and more generally, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ if $n$ is even. This is because a closed hypersurface of an euclidean space has to be orientable.

Comment: If you want an orientable example, take $CP^2$.